# ASP.NET Core 7 Identity + JWT Authentication don't work correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-identity

**Find solution!**

Set the ClockSkew to TimeSpan.Zero

I want to use ASP.NET Core Identity framework and authentication with JWT.

I've injected Identity:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
    {
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
        options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_";
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

And JWT middleware:

```
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, config =>
    {
        var _configuration = builder.Configuration;
        JwtSettings jwtSettings = _configuration.GetSection("Auth").Get<AuthSettings>()!.Jwt; // We already check null

        var secretKey = jwtSettings.Key;

        config.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidIssuer = jwtSettings.Issuer,
            ValidAudience = jwtSettings.Audience,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey)),
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero // since by default the token is valid for 5 minutes, 
                                          // you need to manually configure these properties, 
                                          // which is why you can make the token valid for less than 5 minutes
        };
    });
```

The controller has a `Login` method with an attribute `[Authorize]`:

```
[Authorize()]
[HttpGet()]
public IActionResult Secret()
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Generation token

```
public string GenerateAccessToken(IEnumerable<Claim> claims)
{
    var jwtSettings = _authSettings.Jwt;

    var secretKey = jwtSettings.Key;
    var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey));
    var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        jwtSettings.Issuer,
        jwtSettings.Audience,
        claims,
        expires: DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime(),,
        signingCredentials: signingCredentials
        );

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}
```

But when I send a request with a token that has expired, it gets validated. In `TokenService`, I generate JWT with expiration date "now".

I use `UserManager` and `SignInManager` to authorize user.

What is the problem?

I have already tried changing the order of Identity and JWT implementation.

Comment: Have you tried if token lasting for more than 5 minutes still gets validated? Can you share the code how you generate the token?

Comment: I've added token generation code

Answer (score 0):

The default value of `TokenValidationParameters.ClockSkew` is 5 minutes. You can set the value to a lower value.